# Login failure after successfully adding Ubuntu 22.04 machine to the domain

Tags: login, 22.04, active-directory, sssd

I have successfully added my machine to my company's domain. When I try to login with my domain credentials at the login screen or via su I see a message "Applying machine settings" and the a few seconds later "Failure setting user credentials".

I can use `sudo su - <domain username>` to login and `whoami` and the output of `id` look right. But that's not really helpful for day to day use.

```
local@nick-precision-7560:~$ realm list
dom.mycompany.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: DOM.MYCOMPANY.COM
  domain-name: dom.mycompany.com
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U@dom.mycompany.com
  login-policy: allow-permitted-logins
  permitted-logins: nick@dom.mycompany.com
  permitted-groups: 

local@nick-precision-7560:~$ id nick@dom.mycompany.com
uid=1666422094(nick@dom.mycompany.com) gid=1666400513(domain users@dom.mycompany.com) groups=1666400513(domain users@dom.mycompany.com), ... <many other groups from AD> ...

local@nick-precision-7560:~$ su - nick@dom.mycompany.com
Password: 
Applying machine settings
ERROR Error from server: error while updating policy: can't get policies for "nick-precision-7560.dom.mycompany.com": one or more error while parsing downloaded elements: /var/cache/adsys/sysvol/Policies/{D8DF0C39-D713-439F-8C58-F041634FAD87}/Machine/Registry.pol :can't parse policy: invalid policy: item does not end with ']' 
su: cannot open session: Failure setting user credentials
```

I tried opening this Registry.pol file and it's not very intelligible to me -- it is a mix of binary and ASCII strings. I deleted the entire policy folder so that it would download again and the same policy folder was recreated when I attempted to login again but the results were the same. I've restarted pam and sssd and that doesn't change things. I've restarted the whole system and that doesn't change things.

Here is what my sssd.conf looks like:

```
[sssd]
domains = dom.mycompany.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/dom.mycompany.com]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = DOM.MYCOMPANY.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
id_provider = ad
ldap_sasl_authid = NICK-PRECISI$
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = dom.mycompany.com
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_users = nick
```

EDIT:
I opened the PAM TUI, `sudo pam-auth-update`, and I deselected "ADSys authentication". After doing so I am able to login using my domain credentials without `sudo su -`, and I can also login at the login screen. So it seems like everything is working with SSSD and PAM and the problem related to ADsys.

Since ADSys is new and I've never used it before I am not sure what I'm really missing out on by disabling this. I'm a user and not a domain admin so maybe it really doesn't affect me. I am reluctant to call this the answer because there is clearly still an issue. It's possible that this Registry.pol file is corrupt on the DC.

Comment: I'd like to create a tag for "adsys" and apply it to this question but I don't have enough reputation yet. If someone has the reputation please add the tag.

Comment: What is this PAM TUI you mention?

Comment: `pam-auth-update`. If you run that it will start up a [Terminal User Interface or TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) to configure PAM.